# Get data from a X,Y,Z array within given radius

Tags: c#, arrays, radius

I am developing a game server and currently I need to be able to get spectators within an area, however I fear the one I am using is really ugly and "slow" but I haven't experienced any performance hits yet as I am testing it locally not on a live server.

This is my GetSpectators Function:

```
public void GetSpectators(ref HashSet<Player> Players, Coordinate_t coordinate, bool MultiFloor = false)
        {
            for (int x = coordinate.X - 11; x != coordinate.X + 11; x++)
            {
                for (int y = coordinate.Y - 11; y != coordinate.Y + 11; y++)
                {
                    if (MultiFloor)
                    {
                        for (int z = coordinate.Z - 2; z != coordinate.Z + 2; z++)
                        {
                            Tile tile = GetTile(x, y, z);
                            if (tile != null)
                            {
                                foreach (Player p in tile.Creatures)
                                {
                                    Players.Add(p);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Tile tile = GetTile(x, y, coordinate.Z);
                        if (tile != null)
                        {
                            foreach (Player p in tile.Creatures)
                            {
                                Players.Add(p);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I have this class Map which holds this other dictionary with class Tile, each tile is represented with X, Y, and Z coordinates, each tile holds a list of this class called Player, some tiles have players some don't.

I need a good way and not ugly to get e.g:

All players within x=100, y=100, z=7 in radius 11 for example.

Comment: Not answering your question- you don't need to pass `Players` by `ref`, since you are not assigning a new HashSet<Player> instance to `Players` inside the method.

Comment: Also, `Players` should be `players` and `MultiFloor` should be `multiFloor`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be smart to reference tiles in your `Player` class if you're not already doing so, and then pass the all the players to the `GetSpectators()` method...

Something like...

```
public class Player
{
    // a reference to the tile that the player is currently on.
    public Tile CurrentTile { get; set; }
}
```

This would allow you to loop through the players instead of so many tiles. And it should be cleaner and more efficient to find players the way you want without all the loop nesting. For ex:

```
public List<Player> GetSpectators(Hashset<Player> playersInGame, Coordinate coord)
{
    var playersInRange = new List<Player>();

    // iterate through each player.
    foreach (var p in playersInGame)
    {
        // check if the tile the player is sitting on is in range of radius given.
        if ((p.CurrentTile.X < coord.X + 6 || p.CurrentTile.X > coord.X - 6)
            &&
            (p.CurrentTile.Y < coord.Y + 6 || p.CurrentTile.Y > coord.Y - 6))
        {
            // Player is within radius.
            playersInRange.Add(p);
        }
    }

    return playersInRange;
}
```

You can add in the additional check for Z coordinate, and any other conditional statements. But as you can see, this would allow you to use one loop rather than 3 nested loops. You may or may not find it useful. But I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This really did save my program off 1~2% usage every time a player moved tiles! Marvelous!

Answer (score 0):

You can use circle equation to check whether player lies in the given radius of other player i.e

```
if
x1=100,y1=100,z=7 and r=11

then
(x-x1)^2+(y-y1)^2+(z-z1)^2=r^2.
```

Any point which satisfy this equation will lie in the region.

Comment: Given said that this ***circle equation*** works with an entire square area (e.g; the visible map of a player) does that mean it's faster to just loop through List<Player> than the for (x ... ?

Comment: Yes . Time complexity will be O(n) , where n is the no. of player . less than the 3 nested loop